# Flutter rotate widget

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I rotate the following icon 180 degree? (I want to animate it later and `RotationTransition` is not good choice for me)

```dart
Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down)
```

Comment: *"I want to animate it later and RotationTransition is not good choice for me"* - so why `RotationTransition` is not good? it does animate the child during the transition

Comment: I think `AnimatedContainer` is more cleaner for me

Comment: it has a `transfom`

Comment: but it uses `Matrix4Tween` [under the hood](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart#L772) and `Matrix4Tween` official docs say that: "Currently this class works only for translations."

Comment: But I rotate it by setting `Matrix4.identity()..rotateX(pi)`, my problem is rotation center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can do it by simply using the `Transform` widget.

```
 Transform.rotate(
      angle: pi, // in radians
      child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
  );
```

Comment: How can I do it with `AnimatedContainer` ?

Comment: What do you mean? Exactly the same way. `Transform` is just a "normal" widget, you can use it with whatever you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to animate a rotation, you could also stop the animation at 180° with the animationController:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new IconRotate());
}

class IconRotate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IconRotateState createState() => new _IconRotateState();
}

class _IconRotateState extends State<IconRotate>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this, //for using only a single AnimationController
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 5),
    );

    animationController.repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        child: new Container(
          height: 150.0,
          width: 150.0,
          child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
          return new Transform.rotate(
            angle: animationController.value * 6.3,
            child: _widget,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```